# For a web site, what is the correct way of storing comments in the database?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I wonder what is the right way to store comments to an article/picture/whatever in a database?

Should it be a single table with all the comments like

```
comment_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
is_on      INTEGER REFERENCES content(content_id),
is_by      INTEGER REFERENCES users(user_id),
comment    TEXT
```

or should I create a separate table for every entry and store comments there?

If it's of any significance, I use sqlite.

Comment: All of the answers were helpful, but I ticked N West's one for some extra explanations (maybe someone would later search for an approach he describes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 1 Article for Many comments. A comment can only be associated to one article. So in this case, 2 tables should suffice. Your design looks sufficient. is_on can relate to the article table in a Many to 1 relationship, and is_by would relate to the users table in a 1-1 relationship.

If your design requires that a comment be related to multiple articles, then a three table structure, with the cross reference table ArticleComment (with CommentID and ArticleID) would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a different table for each entry would be bad style. It's generally not a good idea to create tables in your schema depending on content (temporary tables are different obviously).

So your approach is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You have it right in your example - or the right idea at least...

What you probably need it 3 relations:

article
comments
article_comment

Then you would store the article_id and the comment_id in article comments.

Comment: ahh - rereading the formatted question, it would appear you already have this sort of idea :-) Yep this is the best way to go.